# Can someone tell me why my promise queue don't work?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a simple promise queue function, the function will process 50 tasks with 10 concurrent promises:

```
const sendTasks = () => {
  let tasks = 50;
  const concurrentCount = 10;
  let promisePool = 0;

  while (tasks > 0) {
    console.log(`current tasks: ${tasks}`);
    while (promisePool < concurrentCount && task > 0) {
      console.log("create promise");
      tasks--;
      promisePool++;
      const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve("haha");
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) * 1000);
      });

      promise.then((value) => {
        console.log(value);
        promisePool--;
      });

      console.log(`current promisePool: ${promisePool}`);
    }
  }  

  return "done";
};
```

But when I execute it, the promises seems never resolve, then keep stuck in the task>0 while loop. Can someone explain to me why the promises never resolve?

Comment: You never decrement concurrentCount. This is an infinite loop.

Comment: @ddastrodd That count is use to limit my concurrent numbers, so it won't decrement

Comment: @ddastrodd `concurrentCount` is a constant and is not meant to be changed - that controls how many promises should be running at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `while` loop inside a synchronous function will never yield control flow to Promise `.then`s, or to anything else. You will need to restructure the code to wait for the promises to resolve without fully terminating the `sendTasks` function and also without blocking the engine.

One approach is to push each Promise to an array, then await a `Promise.any` on that array. Have the Promises remove themselves from the array when they're finished, and recursively push more Promises to the array. Then return when no more Promises exist in the array.

```js
const sendTasks = async () => {
  let tasks = 50;
  const concurrentCount = 10;
  let promisePool = 0;
  let promises = [];
  const enqueueNext = () => {
    if (!tasks) return;
    // creating this variable just for the sake of logging
    const thisTask = tasks--;
    console.log("create promise", thisTask);
    const prom = new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        promises = promises.filter(p => p !== prom);
        console.log('resolving', thisTask);
        resolve("haha");
        // recursive asynchronous call; init the next promise, if there is one
        enqueueNext();
      }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) * 1000);
    });
    promises.push(prom);
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < concurrentCount; i++) {
    enqueueNext();
  }
  while (promises.length) {
    await Promise.any(promises);
  }
  console.log("done");
};
sendTasks();
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is single-threaded except when it explicitly isn’t (web workers, Node multiprocessing, … – not promises), so your `while (tasks > 0) {` is a busy loop that never returns control to whatever event loop and gives timers the chance to fire.

You need to give a function (`.then`) or continuation (async/await) to your promises so that you can yield back to the event loop and be told when to continue processing.

```js
const sendTasks = async () => {
  let tasks = 50;
  const concurrentCount = 10;
  const promisePool = new Set();

  while (tasks > 0) {
    console.log(`current tasks: ${tasks}`);
    while (promisePool.size < concurrentCount) {
      console.log("create promise");
      tasks--;
      const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve("haha");
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) * 1000);
      });

      promise.then((value) => {
        console.log(value);
        promisePool.delete(promise);
      });

      promisePool.add(promise);

      console.log(`current promisePool: ${[...promisePool]}`);
    }
    
    await Promise.race(promisePool);
  }

  // all tasks have been created here, but not necessarily completed
  await Promise.all(promisePool);

  return "done";
};

sendTasks().then(console.log);
```